# How does one add scores and a total?

Tags: c#

" **When the user clicks the Add Your Scores menu item, add the score for each type of drink to the drink's total**, clear the text boxes, and reset the focus."

I am stuck trying to figure out how to add what is quoted above. I think I am over thinking it and making it harder than what it really is.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Lab6
{      
public partial class NewTester : Form
{
    private int AppleAde;
    private decimal TotalScore;
    private string Winner_Name = ""; 
    int PrunePunch_Score;
    int Total_Num_Of_Tasters;
    decimal Average_Rating_Of_Each_Drink;
    //private decimal Total_Score;
    public NewTester()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashStart));
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        InitializeComponent();

        t.Abort();
    }

    public void SplashStart() {
    Application.Run(new Form2());
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(); 
    }

    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Lab6 by J Soto \nThis lab was started on 10/9/13","About Lab 6",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }

    private void addYourScoresToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   // Vars for text box values...
        PrunePunch_Score = Convert.ToInt32(PrunePunchTextBox.Text);
        AppleAde = Convert.ToInt32(AppleAdeTextBox.Text);


        //...
        if ((PrunePunch_Score <= 10) && (PrunePunch_Score >= 0))
            Convert.ToInt32(PrunePunchTextBox.Text);


        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number between 0 and 10","Prune Punch");
        if ((AppleAde <= 10) && (PrunePunch_Score >= 0))
            Convert.ToInt32(AppleAdeTextBox.Text);

        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number betwen 0 and 10","Apple Ade");

       //...



    }

    private void PrunePunchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrunePunch_Score = Convert.ToInt32(PrunePunchTextBox.Text); 
    }

    private void AppleAdeTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppleAde = Convert.ToInt32(AppleAdeTextBox.Text);

    }

    private void summaryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Summary;

       // Summary= "Winner:"+ Winner_Name "Total Number of Taste Testers:" + Total_Num_Of_Tasters "Average rating for each drink:" + Average_Rating_Of_Each_Drink; 


    }
}
```

}

Comment: The code with "//" is there because I didn't really want to delete it while messing around with my assignment. So if I don't need it, I will delete it later on.

Comment: You add using `+`. As for the rest it's unclear what do you have problem with. Also, please consider reading about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I meant to say how do you keep adding to the result. As in if the result is two and I press the add menu item, it adds another number on top of that. For example: I have 2 and then type 4, then click the menu item again and the result is 6...sort of like adding votes in an election, I want to see what juice brand gets the most number of votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not declare the int at the beginning of your form. simply drag and drop a label which starts at 0. and each score will add it up. convert the label into integer and use += to add value to it.

(P.S. do you have a rar of your project that I can work on?)

Comment: I can make one if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is a big question. I will help out by pointing out that you are calling `Convert` without storing the returned value.

You have things like `Convert.ToInt32(PrunePunchTextBox.Text);` instead of `var value = Convert.ToInt32(PrunePunchTextBox.Text);`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: he already declared them on top _int Total_Num_Of_Tasters;_

Comment: @galleryguy - there are at least 2 cases where he forgot to do the assignment.

Comment: I meant to say how do you keep adding to the result. As in if the result is two and I press the add menu item, it adds another number on top of that. For example: I have 2 and then type 4, then click the menu item again and the result is 6...sort of like adding votes in an election, I want to see what juice brand gets the most number of votes